# Global Variable Vs. Set Function

Tags: c#, function, oop, global-variables, global

I am looking for the best programming practice for changing a variable's value in another class.

For example if I had a boolean to determine if an enemy is facing right of left what would be the best way of going about it?

**A**

```
*outside of Class*
Class.Right = false;

*inside of Class*
public Right = true;
```

**B**

```
*outside of Class*
Class.setRight(false);

*inside of Class*
private Right = true;
public void setRight (right) {
    Right = right;
}
```

Also, I've read that you should avoid using global variables all together, but you should use it in this case because its used in multiple functions within class, right?

Comment: That is not a global variable, it's a public member variable. There is no point in having set functions in C# since you can just use properties.

Comment: Okay I'll stick to the A. I don't think there's a point in implementing properties with every variable at this level.

Answer (score 0):

Use enums and you could go either way with how it's set (we'd need to know details of implementation to provide a specific recommendation).

```
public enum DirectionType{ Right, Left };

public class Enemy
{
    public DirectionType Direction{ get; set; }

    public void HoneInOnHero()
    {
        //Hero's function can help determine position relative to the enemy.
        this.Direction = Hero.GetRelativeDirection(this);
    }
}

var enemy = new Enemy();
enemy.Direction = DirectionType.Left;
//or...
if(attackMode)
    enemy.HoneInOnHero();
```